# How do you find out what conferences are in your field?

Tags: conference

I’m new to the culture of research and my professor suggested that I try to submit an abstract to a conference. The only problem is, I have no idea how you figure out what type of conferences there are. I’m wondering if there’s some type of conference portal that lists them all in different fields...?

There’s so many conferences out there and I’m just curious how one could go about finding conferences to submit to. I should say, I’m not asking what conferences I should submit to, but how you figure out which conferences even exist in the first place.

Comment: Unless things are very different where you are than has been my experience, what you're asking is precisely one of the things a graduate academic adviser should do. However, maybe your professor is interested in seeing what you can come up with first, perhaps as a learning experience?

Answer (score 4):

Another thing that you should do, and it will help with this issue is to join a professional organization in your field. I'll guess that most fields have one or more such organizations, and I'll also guess that most of those have a special rate structure for students. This is true in Mathematics and Computer Science, for example (each of which as two or more such). The ACM (in CS) also has Special Interest Groups (SIGS) for subfields that you can join.

And then, the problem will go away as your email inbox will be full of announcements. Likewise, the "journal" that is distributed to all members will also be full of announcements of conferences, even those not formally sponsored by the organization. The SIGS will also send you lots of enticing ads.

But, you should probably join for a lot of reasons, not just the email "enhancements".

And, of course, those same societies normally have web sites, and their conferences are usually promoted there. They are likely to be some of the top conferences in that field.

Answer (score 3):

Conference Monkey is exactly a "Conference Portal", as you are looking for: at https://conferencemonkey.org/

Beyond it, It's actually one of the main roles of professors in universities and scientific researches to guide students to where and how to submit papers. Thus, actually the most common process is that the professors suggest specific events, journals, etc to their students.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Never heard of this website. Maybe it's field dependent, but it doesn't contain any of the major conferences in my area.

Comment: @henning -- reinstate Monica: *it doesn't contain any of the major conferences in my area* -- I looked at it yesterday and I didn't see anything (major or minor) that reflects more than a small percentage (probably under 2%) of [mathematics](https://conferencemonkey.org/search?physicalscience=mathematics), but from the breakdown of the categories, it might be useful to someone in engineering or economics (but I didn't actually look at the listings under the subheadings in engineering and economics). **(continued)**

Comment: However, the problem with a website like this is there is a large incentive for a worthless conference to be listed and little incentive for a prestigious conference to be listed, and so for someone who doesn't already know which are which in their field, it will be difficult to separate the wheat from the chaff. @Buffy's suggestion to join a professional organization (or at least use their [publications](https://www.ams.org/notices), [web pages](https://euro-math-soc.eu/event-list), etc.) is what I'd consider to be a "first order solution" to the OP's problem.